# how to help 2 devices share local ports behind firewall through a ssh server with ssh reverse tunnel port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port, port-forwarding, tunneling, tunnel

A diagram of the project:
[image: diagram]

It is working under Putty with its GUI configuration, but it is not working if using command line through Putty.

how to replicate the GUI settings in putty with command line?

Comment: What specific putty command are you running? In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

After the complex diagram your actual question and the solution are really simple.

Save all the settings you have made in the GUI as "my session" and then load that session from the command line:

```
d:\path\to\putty.exe -load "my session"
```

> The `-load` option causes PuTTY to load configuration details out of a saved session. If these details include a host name, then this option is all you need to make PuTTY start a session (although Plink still requires an explicitly specified host name). 
>   You need double quotes around the session name if it contains spaces.

Comment: yes, I understand, but my ultimate purpose is to use it in java library with raw ssh command line.  its just puzzling that it works with GUI but the normal command line does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you using the right tool then? [Plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) a [command-line interface](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) to the PuTTY back ends

Comment: I am using the stock putty software under windows 8 .  Its got a command line and some gui features